# How do I get the root directory of a gem in the Rspec tests for my Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I've got a gem, we'll call it `ToastMitten`, which I'm including in one of my Rails apps. I'm writing some tests for `ToastMitten` in which I need to load a file, and I want to specify a path from the root of the gem.

I just tried using `Rails.root.to_s`, but that gives me something like `/Users/me/projects/toastmitten/spec/dummy`. I would have expected that path to end at `toastmitten/`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

```
Rails.root.parent.to_s
```

If it always gives back your dummy Rails app, just move up to the parent.

Comment: That gives me the `spec` folder, which works in this case, but is that what you'd expect?

Comment: Yes, that is what I would expect. Testing Rails plugins/gems with a dummy app is a bit of a pain. I do it for one project I have, changing the setup is very tedious and frustrating.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are using a Rails engine (generated with enginex, hence the dummy app in your spec folder).  If you need to require a file in your test using an absolute path, you can use the following:

```
file = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'path', 'to', 'file.ext'))

root = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', '..'))
```

Can you be more specific on where you are trying to require this file?
Also, The root example may require more `..`'s.

Comment: In an Rspec test several folders deep under `spec`, I am trying to load a file that's in `spec/fixtures`.

Comment: lets say the spec is `spec/f1/f2/blah_spec.rb` you'll want to use `File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', '..', 'fixtures', 'file.txt'))`